# How to post back array of strings from razor view to MVC controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I was getting an string array of input  text box  tags in my view but was unable to post it back to the controller 
My code looks like this, 
**ommitted the unneccessary code for readability**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCivilSurveys" }))
{

 <tbody class="subcategory" id="actualmeasure">

                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <input type="button" class="k-button" value="Add" style="float: right;" id="AddNewActualMeasure" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
<script>

    $("#btnSubmitCivilSurvey").click(function() {

        if ($("#frmCivilSurveys").valid())
        {

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("CivilPostSurvey", "PostSurveyCivils")?ActivityID=" + $("#iPActivityID").val() ,
                    data: JSON.stringify($('#frmCivilSurveys').serializeObject()),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data)
                    {  
                        alert(data.Status);
                        var grid = $("#divSurveyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                        grid.dataSource.read();
                        var win = $("#divEditSurvey").data("kendoWindow");
                        win.close();

                    }

                });


        }
        else
        {

            alert($("#frmCivilSurveys").validate().errorList[0].message);
            $($("#frmCivilSurveys").validate().errorList[0].element).focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

//this is code responsible for creating the arrays of string input textboxes through jquery

```
var m = 1;
$("#AddNewActualMeasure").click(function () {

           $("#actualmeasure").append(' <tr> <td>Measure ' + m + ' </td><td>C/W<input       type="text" id="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td>     <td >F/W <input type="text"  id="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td> </tr>'); //add  input box
             m++; 
        });
</script>
}
```

my controller method looks like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CivilPostSurvey(CivilsPostSurveyViewModel modelData, int ActivityID, string[] CWMeasure,string[] FWMeasure,string[] CWActualMeasure,string[] FWActualMeasure,FormCollection fc)
    {
  // save data 
  return null;//data saved message
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are you posting back to? Show you controller method

Comment: And collections indexers start at `0`, not `1` - `var m = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Stephen your edit suggest that start indexes from 0 solved my problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I see some syntax errors (double `==` and missing spaces)

```
$("#actualmeasure").append(' <tr> <td>Measure ' + m + ' </td><td>C/W<input       type="text"id=="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td>     <td >F/W <input type="text" id=="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td> </tr>');
```

should be

```
$("#actualmeasure").append(' <tr> <td>Measure ' + m + ' </td><td>C/W<input       type="text" id="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="CWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td>     <td >F/W <input type="text"  id="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']" name="FWActualMeasure[' + m + ']"/></td> </tr>');
```

**update**

try changing `tbody` tag into `table` tag.
Another problem I think that should be the id with `[]`.
Escape it with double backslash
 `"string\\['test'\\]"`

no escape sequence is required to correct the error as problem was in indexes not the syntax

Comment: no my problem is still there, I am getting just nulls posted back, whatever i enter in textboxes

Comment: let me know which is the problem